# SplitViewController with multiple DetailViewController that rootViewController and detailviewController both have navigation controller

Tags: ios, ipad

i search for a way to have multiple detail view in iPad application and i find the sample code in apple developer site http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html , but now i want to have navigation Controller in detail view which this sample does not cover, is there any sample cover this kind of application.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can simply initiate a uinavigationcontroller initialized with your views needed and pass it to UISpliviewcontroller at allocation instead of your detailviewcontroller.